# Meteor multilayer collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Salutations; after scouring the web, I still have not found the answer.

I am creating a multiplayer quiz app with a game database that needs to have the score linked to the user id; but I have no idea how to achieve the multidimensional collections, let alone access it in Meteor.  The general idea for the database would be like so:

```
_id                //string
completed          //boolean
mode               //string
users
   id              //string
   id              //string
scores
   playerid1       //string
        score      //int
   playerid2       //string
        score      //int
```

Any insight into how to achieve this depth with Mongo?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the data in Mongo is like json format, in your case, I would recommend create two collection for the data

1. User (You can use Meteor's default user collection)

   ```
   {
      _id : "uid1" //string 
      ....
   }
   ```
2. Game

   ```
   {
     _id : "gid1", //string
     completed : true //boolean
     mode : "" //string
     users : ["uid1", "uid2"] //array of user ids
     scores: {
       "uid1": 15, // UserId: score
       "uid2": 30
     } //Object
   }
   ```

Also, you can use [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) to define your collection modal, that make things easier.